# Android ServiceTestCase for IntentService

Tags: android, servicetestcase

I'm currently writing unit tests for an android application and stumbled into the following issue:

I use the `ServiceTestCase` to test an `IntentService` like this:

```
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();      
}

public void testService()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getSystemContext(), MyIntentService.class);
    super.startService(intent);     
    assertNotNull(getService());        
}
```

However I noticed that my `IntentService` is created (means that `onCreate` is called) but I never receive a call into `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)`

Has anyone already tested an `IntentService` with the `ServiceTestCase` class?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also testing an IntentService and apparantly it isn't setUp properly by the Android Test Framwork. I see no other reason why my tests fail too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975348/strange-nullpointer-exception-in-android-test-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got started into testing my own `IntentService` and it's proving to be a bit of a headache.

Still trying to work things out but for the scenario where it seems that you do not receive a call to your method `onHandleIntent()`, (I'm not very good with the technicalities behind `junit` so forgive my use of terminology) it should be because the test framework, based on your code, actually tears down or end the test method once your call to `startService` returns. There is insufficient time for `onHandleIntent` to be triggered.

I verified the above theory by adding an infinite loop within my test case - only then can I see my log statements in `onHandleIntent` logged.

Comment: You're right, actually the service doesn't start correctly if the unit test is teared down. I fixed it by adding a `Thread.sleep`to the test and periodically check for the service's result.

Comment: I'm currently on the path of using semaphores, but it gets rather clumsy when it comes to knowing when to release the semaphore for the test to be teared down when using IntentService with ResultReceiver. Maybe I should consider using Thread.sleep too

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit late, but I just struggled with this. You could solve this by creating a class that simply overrides the onStart of you service so it calls `onHandleIntent` directly. So for instance, if you have a LocationUpdaterService, you could create a fake class that overrides the `onStart` function like this:

```
public class LocationUpdaterServiceFake extends LocationUpdaterService {

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    onHandleIntent(intent);
    stopSelf(startId);
}
```

`LocationUpdaterService` is a subclass of IntentService, so when you write your tests, just use the `LocationUpdaterServiceFake` class like this

```
public class LocationUpdateServiceTest extends ServiceTestCase<LocationUpdaterServiceFake> {

public LocationUpdateServiceTest()
{
    super(LocationUpdaterServiceFake.class);
}

public void testNewAreaNullLocation()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(LocationUpdaterService.ACTION_NEW_AREA);

    startService(intent);
}
```

}

Now whenever you call `startService`, it will bypass the threading code in IntentService and just call your `onHandleIntent` function

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a:

```
Thread.sleep(XXXXXXX);
```

Choose the `XXXX` after the startService, then it will let the thread go into the `onHandleIntent` method.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 1.1, when running tests using the Run/Debug Configuration | Android Tests facility on any unit under test code (UUT) that extends IntentService, the ServiceTestCase.java (JUnit?) code does not call onHandleIntent(Intent intent) method in the UUT.  ServiceTestCase only calls onCreate so the problem is in the test code.

```
protected void startService(Intent intent) {
    if (!mServiceAttached) {
        setupService();
    }
    assertNotNull(mService);

    if (!mServiceCreated) {
        mService.onCreate();
        mServiceCreated = true;
    }
    mService.onStartCommand(intent, 0, mServiceId);

    mServiceStarted = true;
}
```

In my file smSimulatorTest.java:

```
public class smSimulatorTest extends ServiceTestCase<smSimulator>
```

At this point, I'm looking for other solutions in the testing framework that test UUTs through Intents since this is how IntentService is instantiated.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html - To use it, extend IntentService and implement onHandleIntent(Intent). IntentService will receive the Intents, launch a worker thread, and stop the service as appropriate.

I, like others, put my code in the onHandleintent() as directed by the above documentation, however, ServiceTestCase only tests onStart and onStartCommand has shown above.

Answer (score -1):

This is my approach for now:

1. The start Intent that invokes the service specifies the Service method to test

   ```
   public void test_can_do_the_work() {
       Intent startIntent = new Intent();
       startIntent.putExtra("IN_TEST_MODE", "TEST_SPECIFIC_METHOD");
       startIntent.setClass(getContext(), MyServiceToTest.class);
       startService(startIntent);
       assertNotNull(getService()); // Your assertion Service specific assertion
   }
   ```
2. In the service onStart, we check for the specific Extra passed and call the method to test. This won't execute when Handle intent fired.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);
       String in_test_mode = intent.getStringExtra("TEST_SPECIFIC_METHOD");
       if(in_test_mode != null){
           doServiceWork();
       }
   }
   ```