# How to test an IntentService using a ServiceTestCase?

Tags: android, android-service, android-testing

I have been trying to test my `IntentService` using the Android provided `ServiceTestCase` class, but the tests fail with the `testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly` failing in the first place. My code follows:

```
public class MyClientServiceTest 
   extends ServiceTestCase<MyClientService> {
    public static final String TAG = MyClientServiceTest.class.getName();
    public static final String FILE_PREFIX = "test_";

    private boolean bLoggingIn = false;
    private boolean bLoggingOut = false;
    private boolean bSendingScanRequest = false;
    private boolean bGettingTemplates = false;

    private final Class SERVICE_CLASS = MyClientService.class;

    private RenamingDelegatingContext rdContext = null;

    public MyClientServiceTest() {
        super(MyClientService.class);
    }

    public MyClientServiceTest(Class<MyClientService> serviceType) {
        super(MyClientService.class);   
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        rdContext = new RenamingDelegatingContext
                    (getSystemContext(), FILE_PREFIX);
        setContext(rdContext);
    }

    public void testThrowsExceptionOnNoActionPassedInIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(rdContext, SERVICE_CLASS);
        Exception e = null;
        try{
            startService(intent);
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            e = ex;
        } finally {
            assertNotNull(e);
        }
    }

    public void testThrowsExceptionOnInvalidAction() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(rdContext, SERVICE_CLASS);
        intent.setAction("SurelyInvalidAction");
        Exception e = null;
        try {
            startService(intent);
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            e = ex;
        } finally {
            assertNotNull(e);
        }
    }
}
```

What happens when I try to run this test with JUnit is this:

```
org.itay.mobile.test.MyClientServiceTest
testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly(org.itay.mobile.test.MyClientServiceTest)
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at android.test.ServiceTestCase.setupService(ServiceTestCase.java:152)
at   android.test.ServiceTestCase.testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly(ServiceTestCase.java:330)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)

testThrowsExceptionOnInvalidAction(org.itay.mobile.test.MyClientServiceTest)
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at      org.itay.mobile.test.MyClientServiceTest.testThrowsExceptionOnInvalidAction(MyClientServiceTest.java:61)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)

testThrowsExceptionOnNoActionPassedInIntent(org.itay.mobile.test.MyClientServiceTest)
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at   org.itay.mobile.test.MyClientServiceTest.testThrowsExceptionOnNoActionPassedInIntent(MyClientServiceTest.java:48)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

Even though I have gathered that testing Android IntentServices [especially daunting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667087/android-servicetestcase-for-intentservice), the `testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly` test is failing which means(according to [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/service_testing.html)) that my service failed to initialize a Context properly. How do I do that? If that is not the case (as I *do* initialize a Context using `setContext()` in `setUp()`), what can be done to work around this?

Also, I would highly appreciate someone pointing me to a link that provides general guidelines to Android service testing(with example implementation, of course).

Comment: No I haven't. You mean I should do a setContext(new MockContext()) in setUp()? Or am I missing something?

Comment: protected void setUp() throws Exception {
  super.setUp();  
  setContext(new MockContext());
 }

Comment: doesn't help, testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly fails with the same error (though I had to use a MockContext subclass with an overridden getPackageName())

Comment: I have had success calling AndroidTestCase's getContext() when create an intent for a service testcase, and not setting the context manually. Does your context need to specifically be a RenamingDelegatingContext? If you don't set it manually and breakpoint after setup, what does your context look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to JUnit test IntentService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923181/how-to-junit-test-intentservice)

Comment: @yatisagade Hey, have you found any answer for this? Even my _testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly_ failed.